# Software Updater will not launch in mate

Tags: updates, update-manager, ubuntu-mate

Recently, the software updater in Ubuntu will not launch for what ever reason in Ubuntu Mate. The issue started when I was prompted for a restart to update the system. Once I had restarted the system, I went to open the update manager and found that update manager would open for a brief second and close suddenly (and at other restarts for BIOS change, it would start minimized).

My alternate plan was to start the manager using terminal by getting the launch option in the MATE advanced menu (right clicking software updater and editing the properties). And execute using `/usr/bin/update-manage`. But I get a series of errors as the following.

```
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Dbusmenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Dbusmenu', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity

(update-manager:1063): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(update-manager:1063): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 253, in __del__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So I am wondering on if there is a fix to the issue. I am also using the MATE desktop environment.

Comment: Your question is off topic.  Askubuntu is for supported versions of Ubuntu.  Try one of the other forums such as http://superuser or http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ubuntu MATE *is* a supported version of Ubuntu, therefore on topic at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It's a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1690475

Comment: Installing update notifier fixed the problem for me in Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS. Code: `$ sudo apt-get install update-notifier`